# ZF2 routing configuration

Tags: frameworks, url-routing, zend-framework2

I've just built a zf2 project and i'm having a configuration problem.

When i go to mydomain.com this routs as specified in configuration files to Application module, index controller, index action.

But If i type mydomain.com/otheraction this is not routed to Application module, index controller, otheraction action. Of course, since it isn't configured to do this.

So my question would be how do i configure the app to do that? I've added my Application/config/module.config.php file and the main config file. Thank you!

**module.config.php**

```
    <?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2012 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**application.config.php**

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'ZfcBase',
        'ZfcUser',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default route configured is to accept any url of this format, this is the standard format

```
mydomain.com/
mydomain.com/applicatiom/controller/action (standard format)
```

in your case mydomain.com/otheraction the router expect a module otheraction, but its not present.

if you need to have a route as specified above have a entry under route

```
'otheraction' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/otheraction',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
            'action'     => 'otheraction',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: thanks @Raj ! i've tried it but when i access mydomain.com/application/index/someaction the page loads up but my images are searched in mydomain.com/application/index/images instead of mydomain.com/images. any idea why?

Comment: refer images relative to you root folder ex. images/yourimage.jpg

Answer (score 2):

In the routes subarray, add a next entry similar to the 'home' entry, for example:

```
'user' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/user',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\User',
            'action'     => 'some-action',
        ),
    ),
),
```

That would route yourpage.com/user to `someActionAction` in your `UserController`.