# Route fail to work after migrate and upgrade for ZF2

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2, url-routing

There are three modules in my app/modules/, named Application, Album, Shop. I want to access each of these modules using HOSTANME/application, HOSTNAME/album, and HOSTNAME/shop. For Application modules, the configuration is:

```
 'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'application' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/application',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'AppliWcation\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),


'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController', 
        .........
    ),
 },...
```

There are multiple Controllers under Application module. Via this method, I can accessed URL like: 
    http://www.myhostname.com/application/controllerName/actionName
It is the similar configuration for other two modules.

This works previous T61 thinkpad at beginning of last month. Then I reinstalled Php/apache in my new bought T410. I also git pull latest ZF2 version:

```
git log

commit 73e0de644789aa5b712c97f55c512c57c2b9ac76
Merge: 7c65991 d722da5
Author: Matthew Weier O'Phinney <matthew@zend.com>
Date:   Fri Oct 4 11:01:06 2013 -0500

Merge branch 'hotfix/version-composer'

Fix for issue introduced with #5191
```

But everything does not work anymore. I checked the error.log:

```
[Sun Oct 06 10:47:05 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /path/to/app../ChipShop/public/application
```

However, it works for default route  http://www.myhostname.com.

Is there any wrong in my configuration or some configuration rule has been changed? Thanks

```
[UPDATE]
```

There is similar post [ZF2 routing configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091445/zf2-routing-configuration?rq=1), I tried method:

```
'user' => array(
     'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
     'options' => array(
          'route'    => '/user',
          'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\User',
                'action'     => 'some-action',
            ),
      ),
) ,
```

But it still not work for me..

```
SOLUTION
```


The issue is not in code side. It is in my confiuration. 
1, I forgot to enable apache rewrite module. As what said in akond post.
2, In virtualHost confiuration,

```
 AllowOverride None
```

should be changed to

```
AllowOverride All
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/zendframework/zf2 clearly states that the master branch contains 2.2.5dev. Dev releases are potentially unstable and you should not rely on them. Use composer with

```
"require": {
    "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.2.0"
}
```

and you will be just fine.

---

**Update**

The error message says it cannot find the application directory. Of course it does not exist, since it is virtual. This means that problem is not in the ZF routes at all. Check that

- `.htaccess` file exists in the `public` directory and is of correct content
- Appache is configured to parse this `.htaccess` file
- `mod_rewrite` module is on.
- the directory up to your `public` directory does exist
- and the Virtual Host is attached to this directory.

Comment: I have fixed it..Thank you.. The error message shows it is apache configuration issues.. Just similiar as what you point.:)